# Web API Search string[] using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, contains

I have a Book object with properties like Title, BookId and Genre.

Given a search string, I need to look across all fields and return the books that matches the search string.

My problem is that one of the property Author has type string[] (multiple authors). How do I search through each of the strings in the list to return list of matching records?

The following code works for all the fields except 'Author' as it has string[] type.

```
        var books= ListAllBooks();

        var mv = from m in books
                 select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchStr))
        {
            mv = books.Where(

                (s =>
                       (s.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchStr.ToUpper()))
                    || (s.BookId.ToString().Contains(searchStr))
                    || (s.Classification.ToUpper().Contains(searchStr.ToUpper()))
                    || (s.Genre.ToUpper().Contains(searchStr.ToUpper()))
                    || (s.PublishedDate.ToString().Contains(searchStr))
                    || (s.Authors.Contains(searchStr))


                )).ToList();
        }

        books= mv.ToList();
```

Comment: It is probably better to enumerate the Author string before calling the posted code.  The other searches aren't arrays.  To make the code work with arrays you would need to use searchStr.FirstOrDefault() in the other conditions.

Comment: Not really duplicate as I don't want the return to be bool true/false...

Comment: @jdweng can you please give me an example? i'm new to this so still trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Make posted code a method.  Pass searchStr as a parameter to the method.  When searching for authors call method multiple times (once for each author).